# setSummary of a preference (NullPointerException)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-preferences

I want to set the summary of a Preference when it gets changed. I just  copied the code from the official android tutorials and then changed it to match my needs. - actually I changed nothing essential.

**This all happens in a `onSharedPreferenceChanged` listener**

Unfortunately I get a `NullPointerException` as said below.

```
} else if (key.equals("pulse")) {

    //NullPointerException for .setSummary()

        new SettingsFragment().findPreference(key).setSummary("Current: "
                + sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 2) * 2
                + " seconds");
}
```

I've set this for the preference:

```
android:key="pulse"
```

Any solutions?

```
11-27 18:07:46.873    2009-2009/net.mejmun.hellophone E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at net.mejmun.hellophone.Settings.onSharedPreferenceChanged(Settings.java:56)
```

**EDIT:** now changed it to

```
    } else if (key.equals("pulse")) {

        Log.i(getApplication().getPackageName(), "start");

        Preference Pref = new SettingsFragment().findPreference(key);

        Log.i(getApplication().getPackageName(), "found");

        Pref.setSummary(getString(R.string.toast_pulse_curr)
                + sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 2) * 2
                + getString(R.string.toast_pulse_sec));

        Log.i(getApplication().getPackageName(), "done!");
    }
```

It crashes exactly with `setSummary()`

Answer (score 0):

A `NullPointerException` is thrown whenever the object does not exist.
So the preference apparently doesn't exist, are you sure you have set it already?

You can add a check to see if `findPreference(key)` equals zero, and only if it's not zero run the code.

Or just declare the preference beforehand:

```
} else if (key.equals("pulse")) {

  sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 2);

  /** rest of the code here **/
}
```

**EDIT**:

What if you try to import the preferences in your new Fragment?

But you shoukd import the preferences in the new fragment too.

```
Preference Pref = new SettingsFragment().findPreference(key);

pref.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);  // <-- NEW

Log.i(getApplication().getPackageName(), "found");

Pref.setSummary(getString(R.string.toast_pulse_curr)
        + sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 2) * 2
        + getString(R.string.toast_pulse_sec));
```

Comment: What would the use of `sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 2);` be in that case?

Comment: And yes, I'm sure it exists, because I already used it in previous versions of my app. (Do you mean to check it with `== null`?)

Comment: Yes, I meant `== null`. The use of `sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 2);`is that it tries to acces the key and when the key doesn't already exist it creates the key with value `2`

Comment: Did you import your preferences with `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` ?

Comment: And yes, did this in the Fragment

Comment: Actually I'm not doing this anymore, so I don't have this problem anymore... Yeah, thanks anyway

Comment: Did it work? Some people might have the same problem, so please mark the answer as accepted if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because you are calling it like this...

```
new SettingsFragment().findPreference( key )
```

You're instantiating a new SettingsFragment but you haven't called onCreate on it and the android system doesn't call onCreate on it because you created it yourself instead of via an activity. It is an empty fragment at this point. The findPreference method will return null since the fragment is empty and the call to setSummary will fail.

Your `SettingsFragment` should be the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` listener. Then you will be able to call `findPreference` by itself.